# Control rotation of imageview in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, rotation, android-imageview

I want to control the rotational movement of a crane/excavator-like image in android studio. I have made a program which can rotate lines from `drawLine` and control the movement via button presses.
[This is what i have achieved with drawLine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLL8P.gif).
Now, I want to accomplish the same thing with `imageView` but can't seem to get it. Here is part of my code:

```
    float c1X = parent[0] + child1[0] * ((float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(parent[2])));
    float c1Y = parent[1] + child1[0] * ((float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(parent[2])));

    float c2X = c1X + child2[0] * (((float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(child1[1] + parent[2]))));
    float c2Y = c1Y + child2[0] * (((float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(child1[1] + parent[2]))));

    float c3X = c2X + child3[0] * (((float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(child2[1] + parent[2]))));
    float c3Y = c2Y + child3[0] * (((float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(child2[1] + parent[2]))));

    canvas.drawLine(parent[0],parent[1],c1X,c1Y,linePaint);

    canvas.drawLine(c1X,c1Y,c2X,c2Y,linePaint);

    canvas.drawLine(c2X,c2Y,c3X,c3Y,linePaint);
```

Comment: what does `ImageView` have to do with `Canvas#drawLine`? what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: take images from drawable and control them as I've control the drawLines

Comment: control them? how do you want to control them?

Comment: using button presses to move a rectangle up and down around a pivot at one end of the shape, like an excavator arm/crane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Bitmap instead ImageView. Load image into Bitmap and draw it on canvas.

Comment: This. I have been racking my brains out how to achieve this. Any resources I can read?

Comment: exactly. it is hard an example that i can play off. been reading a lot tbh

Comment: But I will show how to do it: 1) Create field which controls rotation degree (private float degree; ) 2) create bitmap with your resource (see BitmapFactory.decode... methods) and draw it on canvas  (canvas.drawBitmap method) 3) after, rotate canvas by degree field (canvas.rotate method) 4) write method like a public void rotateImage(float degree) { this.degree = degree; invalidate(); } invalidate() redraws your custom view 5) when you press button call  rotateImage method of your custom view.  Also see restore and save methods of Canvas.

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137568/rotate-bitmap-on-canvas-android

Comment: This actually solves the problem with rotating ONE image alone. I need to rotate 3 connected images together. When the main arm moves, side and final arm moves along. When the side arm moves, the final arm moves alone and the main arm stays in place. When the final arm moves, the main and side arm stays in place.

Comment: Then canvas can't to help you. There are setRotation and setTranslation methods in ImageView. Add imageviews to RelativeLayout and manipulate them with methods above I said.

Comment: I have updated the problem and added a GIF to show what Ive done. Do you think its achievable in android studio? Using bitmap?

Comment: Sure, It's possible. When I told you with canvas you can't do, I meant your calculations will be very complicated. You may rotate all three bitmap individually like this: canvas.save(); canvas.rotate(angle1, centerX1, centerY1); canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1); canvas.restore(); canvas.rotate(angle2, centerX2, centerY2); canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2); canvas.restore(); canvas.rotate(angle3, centerX3, centerY3); canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap3); canvas.restore()

Comment: I'll do this right now. Thanks for the great insight so far. I'll be sure to show you the results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't actually use an image view but it's an awesome dial control for Android: https://bitbucket.org/warwick/hgdialrepo
And here is the youtube demo: https://youtu.be/h_7VxrZ2W-g
This should server all your rotaion needs.